# Solr StandardTokenizerFactory keep one char

Tags: search, solr, tokenize

I want to keep one character the "@" sign when using the standardtokenizer from solr/lucene, and let it do its work. Is that possible? I've been going through the different tokenizers and it seems that this is not built in. Is that correct?

Comment: In case you are still interested in the answer, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713314/dont-split-on-underscore-with-solr-standardtokenizerfactory